# How to send parameter to jsonresult action in a controller in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc

I have an issue that I have been stuck with for some time .

I have a `JsonResult` method in my Controller (SubSubCategoriesController):-

```
 public JsonResult GetSubCategories(int CategoryID)
    {
        return Json((db.SubCategories.Select(p => new { CategoryID = p.CategoryID, SubCategoryID = p.SubCatgeoryID, SubCategoryName = p.SubCategoryName })).Where(p => p.CategoryID == CategoryID), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Now, I want to send the value of parameter (CategoryID) from my View? How Can i achieve this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Show your view code that calls this method

Comment: @StephenMuecke I did try some `HTML Helpers` but nothing succeeded

Comment: @Medo you need to do this via a javascript ajax call. Have you written this? If so, please show it.

Comment: you can use ajax call from view to send the `CategoryID`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is not structured in viewmodel,I mean if you are only interested to send a single parameter then you can use below ajax function defining it from the view.

```
$.ajax({
         type: 'GET',
         url: '<%= Url.Action("GetSubCategories") %>',
         cache: false,
         data: { CategoryID : <bind it from UI> },
         success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);  
         },
         error: function (xhr) {
            alert('Error: ' + xhr.statusText);    
         }
});
```

Or else another neat way

```
$.post( "controller/method", {CategoryID: "<From UI>"}, function(result) {
  console.log(result)
});
```

And just decorate the action method with `httpPost`

```
[httpPost]
public JsonResult GetSubCategories(int CategoryID)
{
}
```

See [$.post here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/).